# Kotlin - @AliasFor not overriding attribute from @DisplayName

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, junit, annotations

I'm trying to create an annotation for tests with a few meta-annotations. I'd like to pass a `name` parameter and use it for `@DisplayName`'s value, by using `@AliasFor`. The code looks like this:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Nested
@DisplayName("")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
internal annotation class EndpointTest(
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = DisplayName::class, attribute = "value")
    val name: String
)
```

The value of `@DisplayName` is not being overriden, which is unexpected. It seems to be completely ignored. I used `""` here because value does not have a default value

Answer (score 0):

`@AliasFor` is a Spring annotation and requires the use of Spring's annotation searching facilities to support it.

`@DisplayName` is a JUnit Jupiter annotation and is only looked up via JUnit 5's annotation support utilities (which do not include support for Spring's `@AliasFor` annotation).

Thus, JUnit will never interpret the `name` attribute in your `@EndpointTest` annotation as the `value` of `@DisplayName`.